# Setting value to a TextField from JQuery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textfield defined below; I need to set a value to this text field from the JQuery method. The JQuery method is being called, but the value is not getting displayed.

```
<input type="text" id="br_name" name="br_name" />
```

```
$(function () {
    $('.senddb').click(function () {
         $(".br_name").attr("value", $(this).data("bankbranchName"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing some things up. You need to get elements with an id via "#idname" and elements with a class via ".classname". Use jQuerys .val() method to set and get input values. Also your data attribute shouldn't be camelcase.

http://jsfiddle.net/Dtk67/

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="br_name" name="br_name" />
<button class="senddb" data-bankbranchname="foo">Button</button>
```

JS

```
$('.senddb').click(function () {
    $("#br_name").val($(this).data("bankbranchname"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get or set the `value` *property* of a text input, use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method:

```
$(function () {
    $('.senddb').click(function () {
        $(".br_name").val($(this).data("bankbranchName"));
    });
});
```

Comment: It's not getting displayed.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the id selector instead of a class selector 
`$("#br_name").val($(this).data("bankbranchName"));`